# Retrofit - Bearer Token

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, dagger-hilt

I am using Retrofit in my project and I'm trying to accomplish a get request attached with Bearer token.

In the API documentation (https://the-one-api.dev/documentation) it says:

> "You need to send the access key as a bearer token in every request
> you make to the api. Bearer tokens must be included in the
> authorization header in the following format:
>
> *Authorization: Bearer your-api-key-123*
>
> ... Only the /book endpoint is available without authentication."

When i run the below code it gives "HTTP 401 Unauthorized". (Not in book requests but in movie request). I tried "Authorization: xxx" and "Authorization: Bearer xxx", both failed (xxx = My token).

**API:**

```
interface LotrApi {

    @GET("book")
    suspend fun getBookList(): BookListDto

    @GET("book/{id}/chapter")
    suspend fun getBookChapterList(
        @Path("id") id : String,
    ): BookChapterListDto

    @GET("movie")
    suspend fun getMovieList(
        @Header("Authorization") authHeader : String
    ): MovieListDto
}
```

**Repository:**

```
class MovieRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: LotrApi
) {
    fun getMovies(header : String): Flow<Resource<List<Movie>>> = flow {
        try {
            emit(Resource.Loading<List<Movie>>())
            val movies = api.getMovieList(header).MovieListDtoToMovieList()
            emit(Resource.Loading<List<Movie>>(movies))
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            emit(Resource.Error<List<Movie>>("Unexpected Error"))
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            emit(Resource.Error<List<Movie>>("Please check your internet connection"))
        }
    }
}
```

**MovieListDto:**

```
data class MovieListDto(
    val docs: List<Movie>,
    val limit: Int,
    val offset: Int,
    val page: Int,
    val pages: Int,
    val total: Int
)

fun MovieListDto.MovieListDtoToMovieList() : List<Movie> {
    return docs
}
```

Comment: The problem solved when I typed header as "Bearer: " + "XXX". I don't understand why but it did.

Comment: It's odd, normally using "Authorization" as a key and "Bearer xxx" as a value is standard. Btw, I encourage you to look into Interceptor to handle such logic instead of inserting such headers individually into all your authenticated requests ;)